# 3D surface graph with matplotlib using dataframe columns to input the data

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, 3d

I have a spreadsheet file that I would like to input to create a 3D surface graph using Matplotlib in Python.

I used `plot_trisurf` and it worked, but I need the projections of the contour profiles onto the graph that I can get with the surface function, [like this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/mplot3d/contour3d_3.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-contour3d-3-py).

I'm struggling to arrange my Z data in a 2D array that I can use to input in the `plot_surface` method. I tried a lot of things, but none seems to work.

Here it is what I have working, using `plot_trisurf`

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel ("/Users/carolethais/Desktop/Dissertação Carol/Códigos/Resultados/res_02_0.5.xlsx")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
# I got the graph using trisurf 
graf=ax.plot_trisurf(df["Diametro"],df["Comprimento"], df["temp_out"], cmap=matplotlib.cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlim(0, 0.5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax.set_zlim(25,40)
fig.colorbar(graf, shrink=0.5, aspect=15)
ax.set_xlabel('Diâmetro (m)')
ax.set_ylabel('Comprimento (m)')
ax.set_zlabel('Temperatura de Saída (ºC)')

plt.show()
```

[image]

This is a part of my df, dataframe:

```py
       Diametro  Comprimento   temp_out
0      0.334294     0.787092  34.801994
1      0.334294     8.187065  32.465551
2      0.334294    26.155976  29.206090
3      0.334294    43.648591  27.792126
4      0.334294    60.768219  27.163233
...         ...          ...        ...
59995  0.437266    14.113660  31.947302
59996  0.437266    25.208851  30.317583
59997  0.437266    33.823035  29.405461
59998  0.437266    57.724209  27.891616
59999  0.437266    62.455890  27.709298
```

I tried [this approach](https://superuser.com/questions/1328448/3d-plot-with-matplotlib-from-imported-data) to use the imported data with `plot_surface`, but what I got was indeed a graph but it didn't work, here it's the way the graph looked with this approach:
[image]
Thank you so much

Comment: It's really difficult to help you without any significant info.  What have you done, how is your data organized, what have you tried...

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my first question here. I edited the question with more information if you could take a look I would be very happy. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that you have 60000 points, are they disposed on a regular grid? 300x200 maybe? If the points are indeed on a regular grid you can reshape your data in the format required for `plot_surface`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach, based on re-gridding the data, that doesn't require that the original data is specified on a regular grid [deeply inspired by [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html);-].

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.tri as tri
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

np.random.seed(19880808)

# compute the sombrero over a cloud of random points
npts = 10000
x, y = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, npts), np.random.uniform(-5, 5, npts)
z = np.cos(1.5*np.sqrt(x*x + y*y))/(1+0.33*(x*x+y*y))

# prepare the interpolator
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
interpolator = tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang, z)

# do the interpolation
xi = yi = np.linspace(-5, 5, 101)
Xi, Yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
Zi = interpolator(Xi, Yi)

# plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
norm = plt.Normalize(-1,1)
ax.plot_surface(Xi, Yi, Zi,
                cmap='inferno',
                norm=plt.Normalize(-1,1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply earlier... It worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`plot_trisurf` expects `x, y, z` as 1D arrays while `plot_surface` expects `X, Y, Z` as 2D arrays or as `x, y, Z` with `x, y` being 1D array and `Z` a 2D array.

Your data consists of 3 1D arrays, so plotting them with `plot_trisurf` is immediate but you need to use `plot_surface` to be able to project the isolines on the coordinate planes... You need to reshape your data.

It seems that you have 60000 data points, **in the following I assume that you have a regular grid** 300 points in the x direction and 200 points in y — but what is important is the idea of regular grid.

The code below shows

1. the use of `plot_trisurf` (with a coarser mesh), similar to your code;
2. the correct use of reshaping and its application in `plot_surface`;
   note that the number of rows in reshaping corresponds to the number
   of points in y and the number of columns to the number of points in x;
3. and 4. incorrect use of reshaping, the resulting subplots are somehow
   similar to the plot you showed, maybe you just need to fix the number
   of row and columns.

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x, y = np.arange(30)/3.-5, np.arange(20)/2.-5
x, y = (arr.flatten() for arr in np.meshgrid(x, y))
z = np.cos(1.5*np.sqrt(x*x + y*y))/(1+0.1*(x*x+y*y))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, subplot_kw={"projection" : "3d"})
axes = iter(axes.flatten())

ax = next(axes)
ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z, cmap='Reds')
ax.set_title('Trisurf')

X, Y, Z = (arr.reshape(20,30) for arr in (x,y,z))
ax = next(axes)
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap='Reds')
ax.set_title('Surface 20×30')

X, Y, Z = (arr.reshape(30,20) for arr in (x,y,z))
ax = next(axes)
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap='Reds')
ax.set_title('Surface 30×20')

X, Y, Z = (arr.reshape(40,15) for arr in (x,y,z))
ax = next(axes)
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap='Reds')
ax.set_title('Surface 40×15')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped a lot. Now I realize I don't have a regular grid. My x has 1000 unique numbers and my y has 60000. The numbers are very close to each other (like 0.00112 - 0.00113), but they are not exactly the same. So, in order to overcome this issue I need to do something like this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html ?

Comment: The "irregular data grid" looks like the way to go...  I'll post an example